# Electron.js not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, nuxt.js

I'm use vue.js + nuxt.js + electron

I'm installing nuxt.js and electron.js fully

After creating new project with help command `vue init nuxt-community/electron-template my-project`

i run `npm run dev`, end see next error in the logs

```
10 silly lifecycle planster@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'cross-env NODE_ENV=DEV electron .' ]
11 silly lifecycle planster@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle planster@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: planster@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=DEV electron .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid planster@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd E:\PROJECTS\PLANSTER\PRODUCTIONS\DESCKTOP\planster
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v8.11.1
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error planster@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=DEV electron .`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the planster@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm use win7. How to solve my problem?

Comment: What shell are you using to run the command?

Comment: it looks like you might not have run `npm install` before you ran `npm run dev`.

Comment: @LShapz
Thank you! All work